# MVC Route issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a following problem. Route looks like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Test",
            "{controller}/{action}/{test}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Test" }
        );
```

In my controller I have this method:

```
    public void Test(string testParam)
    {

    }
```

And in my view I have following code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test","Test", new { testParam = "bla"} )
```

I suppose that my `url` after clicking on link should look like this:

```
...Home/Test/bla
```

but this is not the case, `url` looks like this:

```
...Home/Test?testParam=bla
```

in RouteData i do not have testParam as key or value...i only have controller and action. And im RouteData/Route i have following target url controller/action/id, and that is wrong route

[image: in RouteData i do not have testParam as key or value...i only have controller and action. And im RouteData/Route i have following target url controller/action/id]

Answer (score 1):

Change your route to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Test",
    "{controller}/{action}/{test}/{testparam}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Test", testparam = UrlParameter.Optional  }
);
```

Comment: thanks for fast reply, but after changing my route, the problem still remains the same

Comment: Its ok now, i switched back to default route, url is fine now